# How to make Accordion Panel-title clickable area bigger

Tags: angularjs, css

I am trying to make the entire panel-heading click-able. I tried wrapping the div with some css. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2gDYinxOrIAELLZ2G8o?p=preview)

```css
#box {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a id="box">
    <div class="panel-heading" toggle target="collapse{{$index}}">
       <h4 class="panel-title">
          <span style="font-size:12px">Name :</span> <span ng-click="selectJob(currentItem, $index)">{{currentItem.JobName}}</span>
       </h4>
     </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Looks like it works. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: sorry, I need the ng-click to be triggered. if you look in the console you will see when you click on the title vs the entire panel-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `ngClick` to `a` element:

```
<a id="box" ng-click="selectEmployee(employee, $index)">
    <div class="panel-heading" toggle target="collapse{{$index}}">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <span>{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}}</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
</a>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nOGHHQWxT5lEKbulmGtJ?p=preview